# ios comparing string in a nsmutabledictionary wtih a string I got this error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have this line of code where I'm trying to compare a string inside of nsmutabledictinary to string:

```
if ([[[myDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"time"] stringValue]  isEqualToString:@"hours"])
```

but I'm getting this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString
>   stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3a4849a4'

I check the type of class of the dictionary container:

```
NSLog(@"%@'", NSStringFromClass([[myDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"time"]  class]));
```

this is the output:

```
__NSCFConstantString
```

any of you knows why or how can fix this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Since you already have a string (`NSString`), don't call `stringValue` on it. And do you really mean to use `valueForKeyPath:` and not `objectForKey:`?

Comment: Can't really assume it's an `NSString`, but it seems like in this case, it is.

Answer (score 2):

```
[myDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"time"]
```

It is already an `NSString`. There is no need to call `-stringValue` to convert it to a string. 
Why are you doing that ? 
Instead of using `-valueForKeyPath`, you should write it like this :

```
if ([[myDictionary objectForKey:@"time"] isEqualToString:@"hours"])
```

Comment: is not a nsstring. is a string inside of a dictionary.

Comment: @Vin You mean `objectForKey:` should be used, not `valueForKey:`.

Answer (score 0):

NSString does not have a `stringValue` method. You've likely seen this sort of thing used to turn an NSNumber in a dictionary into a string.

It seems likely that what you really want to do is:

```
if ([myDictionary[@"time"] isEqualToString:@"hours"]) {
    ...
```